# I got this error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont) while updating the latest Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Consider:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        apply plugin: 'announce'
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories
    {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{ url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle (maybe here is the cause of error)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "chocolahat.softeng.sweetbitescafe"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // My Library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.2'

    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'

    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.1'

    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### ERROR (unfortunately the application has stopped)

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: chocolahat.softeng.sweetbitescafe, PID: 26876
>                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/chocolahat.softeng.sweetbitescafe-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                             at chocolahat.softeng.sweetbitescafe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
>                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

*the MainActivity.java:18 line code is this*
**setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

How can I solve this?

Comment: defined or declared any custom font attributes ?

Comment: appears that you are using a **custom text view** and *font path* that you gave is invalid.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: please post your custom view code

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

API level 26 has come up with its default `font` attribute. And the same font attribute might have been defined in code as part of the `custom font attribute`.

Solution: change your custom font attribute name.

Like `font` to `custom_font` and use in XML files as `custom_font:`

The same changes will be applied in your Java code as well.

Comment: i didn't declared any custom font

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' is not working for me

Comment: Re *"will be applied"*: Do you mean *"must be applied"*? If yes, respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48848981/edit), not here in comments. Or otherwise edit to make it more clear (if required).